# Using Variables/Parameters in SQLCommand

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I am using the following code to get a user's full name, then
I am attempting to use the user's full name to then find out their ID, department and job title.  Is there a way to use the DirectoryEntry to also acquire the EmplID from active directory?

```
public  void Connect()
{
    //method to connect to database and autofill user information
    string n = GetFullName();
    string[] names = n.Split(',');
    FullName.Text = n;

    fn = names[1];
    ln = names[0];

    try
    {

        var connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PSHRDataConnection"];
        SqlConnection ds = new SqlConnection(connection.ConnectionString);

        ds.Open();

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select EmpID, psd.Descr, JobCode from PSHRData ps Inner Join PSDept psd on psd.DeptID=ps.DeptID where ps.LastName =@lname and ps.FirstName=@fname", ds);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fn);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", ln);
        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            EmID.Text = reader["EmpID"].ToString();
            dept.Text = reader["Descr"].ToString();
            jobtitle.Text = reader["JobCode"].ToString();
        }

        ds.Close();
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {

    }
}
```

This works properly when I replace the 2 parameters with my actual first and last name, but does not seem to want to accept the parameters for what ever reason (no error is thrown, just doesn't populate the information that it is supposed to)

Comment: The `WinNT://` namespace reads the data using the NetXXX APIs, not the Active Directory APIs. 

You probably  want to use `ldap://` namespace

Comment: @Ben so I can acquire the EmplID by using the ldap:// instead of the WinNt://? If so, how?

Comment: Remove the empty catch block. That's just going to swallow exceptions. If you're going to catch them, at least log them.